# Sum of the output of another query OR total of sums in one query - Grafana Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

Here are my two queries. With query B, I would like to sum the itemNumberDone of query A.
I also would also like a query C that sum the itemNumberInError of query A.

[image]

[image]

If what I am asking previously is not possible, I would like that my query A shows me the total of all the itemNumberDone after the group by. The items need to be grouped by and I want the items with the max timestamp like I did in the query. Currently, it doesn't show me a total in the pie chart but many sums.

I use Grafana v6.2.5,
Thank you